# Validation Rule-If Active checkbox in unchecked, then Reason for cancellation is mandatory Applicable only to record type End Client

Tags: validation-rule

This is the Validation for Account Object -Person Account

If Active checkbox in unchecked, then Reason for cancellation is mandatory 
Applicable only to record type End Client

And I have written the answer as follow but it's not working

```
AND(
PersonContact.Account.RecordType.DeveloperName = "End Client",
 IF(Active__c = FALSE, 
NOT(ISBLANK( TEXT( Reason_for_Cancellation__c ) )),
ISBLANK(TEXT( Reason_for_Cancellation__c ) )
)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

For sure the first problem you have concerned the record type developer name "End Client" because space character is not allowed for a developername. So try the developer name "End_Client" or to be sure check in the SF setting the developer name of this developer name. 
Secondly, I am also surprised because you check the record type concerning the account of "PersonContact" lookup and not the record type of the direct account (but maybe its your need).

So try that :

```
AND(
PersonContact.Account.RecordType.DeveloperName = "End_Client",
NOT(Active__c), 
ISBLANK(TEXT( Reason_for_Cancellation__c ) )
)
```

Or if you want to check the record type of the account record that :

```
AND(
RecordType.DeveloperName = "End_Client",
NOT(Active__c), 
ISBLANK(TEXT( Reason_for_Cancellation__c ) )
)
```

And if it doesn't work check the RecordType API Name in your SF Setup

Comment: Hi Athiras,
My second code formula answers to your need and I think it is better because I advise you to use "RecordType.DeveloperName" instead of "RecordType.Name". It's more safe because generally we never edit the developer_name whereas the name can be changed with the time :)

Comment: Don't forget to mark one anwser to "accept" in order to close your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your Response and its correct .But the error was with my Logic.
And here I would like to share the answer which worked for me.

AND(
RecordType.Name = "End Client",
ISBLANK(TEXT( Reason_for_Cancellation__c )),
Active__c = FALSE
)